# Setting filters in ui-grid doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to set the filter in `ui-grid` pragmatically but doesn't seem to work with ranges.

This [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/PKHGbj8Rf57cqA3tO3Xl?p=preview) shows one of the filters working perfectly (the name). But the age filter populates the input box but doesn't appear to update the grid's filter.
Do I have to manually update the filter?

I have also tried setting the entire filter when the button is clicked by:

```
$scope.ageColumn.filters=$scope.ageFilter;
```

but that also doesn't work.

Any idea how to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like we need the term to be a string - when it's a number it doesn't work.

```
$scope.ageColumn.filters[0].term='30';
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/2TvIqdKYeRuYXUx1bRNo?p=preview

Not sure why that would be the case, so I need to take a look at that.

Comment: I've also raised a ui-grid issue: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/3568